# Non-persistent annoying message

Tags: .net, invoke, splash-screen, begininvoke

Annoying message from time to time on my .Net application start appears just after splash screen disappears:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
```

I don't know how to fix this type of exceptions and why it appears?

Any help will be appreciated.!

Comment: What splash screen are you using? One that you wrote yourself? Post the relevant code.

Comment: No, I use the splash screen comes as a template with VS2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem usually happens if you add code to the constructor of a form/control, since at that time it isn't linked to a windows control handle. If you *have* added extra code here, try moving it to `OnLoaded` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to invoke a method belonging to a class instance as not previously created, make sure that the invocations of methods or functions of classes or objects after a re made ​​explicit initialization.

```
Call myClass_Method  'or myObject_method
myClass as <objecttype> = New <objecttype>
```

Make sure it is as follows:

```
myClass as <objecttype> = New <objecttype>
Call myClass_Method 'or myObject_method
```

That I guess since you do not give more details or code samples

Comment: This seems very ... hard to interpret. But I *think* what you are describing is a `NullReferenceException`, which is completely unrelated to the question (which is a windows control handle issue).